# Can I use VLAN for this scenario?

Tags: networking, vpn, vlan

I have a scenario where I have servers and computers at two different locations, one of the locations require that two different networks are available. It's a form of DMZ.

The setup is made by the following parts.

**Router X**

- Comes from my ISP and is managed by them
- It has five ports with separate IP's, marked as 10.10.0.x in my schema

**Router Y**

- Is an internal router I use to get an internal class C network

What I would like to do is to get rid of the red cable and have both my 192.168.100.0 network and the 10.10.0.x network through one cable if it's possible. The best scenario for me would be some sort of tunneling (possibly vlan?) using this kind of switches http://www.netgear.com/business/products/switches/prosafe-plus-switches/gs105e.aspx.

My network
[image]

Comment: Ideally, where in your network do you want to connect server 10.10.0.10?  Is this server exposed to the Internet using NAT (Network Address Transaction) in router X?  Is that why it needs to keep an IP address in subnet 10.10.0.0/24 (or whatever subnet your 10.10.0.x addresses are in)?

Comment: The only requirement is that the 10.10.0.10 server can keep an external address from the X router. The 10.10.0.10 and 10.10.0.11 are actually external ip's directly to the internet and not class A networks in that sense (sorry).

Comment: Actually, 10.0.0.0/8 is a [private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) - class A IP network.  Getting that IP address to work in your network when not connected to router X will be a challenge.

Comment: I know, I cloaked the IP's since I don't want to reveal them here. The actual IPs are more like 85.228.18.22 and 85.228.18.78

Comment: If the machine you want to move is a web server, one idea is that you can use Apache's mod_proxy and create a reverse proxy in your 10.10.0.0 network and forward the requests to wherever you place the actual web server in your internal network.